# apostrophe+S vs OF vs nothing

Tags: comprehension

I read many texts about when to use ‘s or of, but still can’t understand it completely.
I was trying to say that someone went to the gate which gives entrance to a mall. There are four ways I can think this can be written:

1. She went to the gate to the mall.
2. She went to the gate of the mall.
3. She went to the mall gate.
4. She went to the mall’s gate.

I think 1 conveys the idea that the person went to a gate which gives entrance to the mall, without it being necessarily the only existing gate there, while 2 conveys the idea the person went to the only gate to the mall.

3 is equivalent to 2, but maybe sounds more idiomatic. While 4 is not wrong if we consider it’s a given mall already strongly considered by the interlocutor, but for some reason it seems wrong to me (even though it's the option that makes the most sense according to my personal reasoning).

Is 4 really wrong?

Can someone help me to understand what the differences are, please?

Comment: In general, 'apostrophe s' is used more often for people and 'of the' for things, but that isn't a hard and fast rule. (_The man's hat_ but _the hat of the man with the red beard_.) _The town's edge_ or _the mall's gate_ are not wrong, but unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to start with, the difference between "of" and "to" in this context:

> The gate **to** the mall

This says that going through the gate will lead to the mall.  It does not say anything about what the gate is attached to or associated with.  The gate itself may not really be anywhere near the mall at all, but, from where you're standing right now, that is the gate you need to go through if you want to (eventually) get to the mall.  (So, for example, if you're in a garden and one of the gates of the garden leads to a path that leads to the mall, that would be the "gate to the mall" even though it's really a gate of the garden, not a gate of the mall)

> The gate **of** the mall

This says that the gate is owned by or associated with the mall.  This does not technically say anything about where the gate leads to, but since gates that are associated with a location are usually around the outside and allow entry into the area, it's implied that the "gate of the mall" probably allows you to get into the mall (but this may not necessarily be the case, if something else indicates it goes somewhere else, for example).

Now, regarding your other two options:

> The mall's gate

This means pretty much exactly the same thing as "the gate of the mall", just in a different form.  The gate is owned by or associated with the mall.

> The mall gate

This is not technically correct, although people may often say things like this, and when they do they generally mean it to be the same meaning as "the mall's gate".

This might be correct if there was a compound noun called "mall gate" which meant something different than "gate" (but as far as I know there isn't in this case).  In that case, "mall" would be essentially being used as an adjective to indicate a particular style or type of gate (maybe a style of gate that's usually used in malls, as opposed to elsewhere).  An example of this would be "toll gate", which is a particular type of gate used for collecting tolls as people pass through it, etc.

I don't think any of these really convey a particular sense of whether there's more than one gate or not.  In common usage, many people will use all of these interchangeably, but there may be a few situations (such as the garden example) where only one or the other actually technically works.

Comment: Thank you very much. Perfect!